# How can I cancel ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument()?

Tags: android

I have an Android app in which I need to prompt the user to pick a file from their documents or downloads folder. The code I'm using looks like this:

```
var filePickerLauncher: ActivityResultLauncher<Array<String>> = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument()) { uri: Uri? ->...

filePickerLauncher.launch("*/*")
```

The problem I'm having is that there isn't any "cancel" or "back" button on the screen that appears. The user cannot proceed without picking a file. Why isn't there a cancel button and how do I get one to appear?

Comment: Android users use the system back gesture to go back.